# PHP app not progressing past require_once

Tags: php

I am having difficulty getting a PHP app to progress past a require_once statement.  My PHP code is located in the body of an HTML5 document.  I am trying to include the PHpass framework in my code for password hashing. The PHP code begins something to the effect of this:

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/PasswordHash.php");
echo "test.";
?>
```

The echo statement never runs and nothing below the echo statement runs, either.  If I comment out the require statement, then the echo statement runs fine.  I am not receiving any error messages, I'm only getting a blank document.

What am I screwing up?

Comment: make sure error checking and display are on. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Add these two lines to the top of the script: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); Then run it again and post the output back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file which you load does not exists or you have not permission to read it.

Turn on displaying errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's many possibilities, thus I wrote about error_reporting.

Comment: This was the solution.  It was a permission glitch.  I assumed permissions would be ok since I had already configured them previously, but given that I had downloaded the include file the permissions were messed up on that one file only.  After adjusting to 644, the problem is solved.  error_reporting(E_ALL) still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

Either your `require_once` fails and you don't see the output, or the included script fails unrecoverably. You should still be able to see the stack trace in the Apache error log I think, but you should always turn error reporting *On* on development machines.

BTW, *current directory* in PHP scripts is somewhat tricky. When you want to refer to a file with a path relative to the script `require` appears into, I suggest something like

```php
<?php
// Use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of forward slash for OS independence
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/included.php');
// or you can replace dirname(__FILE__) with __DIR__
```

note the use of the magic constant [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: I was using the (dirname(__FILE__) format.  I changed it to the dot notation to make my post simpler as I was trying to isolate the root of the issue.  Thanks for the advice, though.  :)

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't really buy us anything here. A message description is the only helpful thing, and so you shluld really turn error reporting On :)